# Why is my ml model returning VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation instead VNRecognizedObjectObservation?

Tags: coreml, vision, coremltools, createml, visionkit

I'm training a machine learning model in PyTorch using [YOLOv5 from Ultralytics.](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)

[CoreMLTools from Apple](https://github.com/apple/coremltools) is used to convert the PyTorch (.pt) model into a CoreML model (.mlmodel).

This works fine, and I can use it in my iOS App, but I have to access the prediction output of the Model "manually".
The output shape of the model is `MultiArray : Float32 1 × 25500 × 46 array`.

From the `VNCoreMLRequest` I receive only `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation`   from this I can get the MultiArray and iterate through it, to find the data I need.

But I see that Apple offers for Object Detection models `VNRecognizedObjectObservation` type, which is not returned for my model.

**What is the reason why my model is not supported to return the `VNRecognizedObjectObservation` type? Can I use CoreMLTools to enable it?**

[image]